# How can we get files mime-type/content-type in download/upload dropbbox methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dropbox, dropbox-api

Here we are trying to identifying uploaded/downloaded files `mime-type/content-type`.

We are using below methods.
For downloading:

```
dropBoxClient.Files.DownloadAsync(filePath)
```

For uploading:

```
dropBoxClient.Files.UploadAsync(filePath)
```

Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     private  string GetMimeType(string fileName)
>     {
>         string mimeType = "application/unknown";
>         string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
>         Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
>         if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)  
>         mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
>         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mimeType);  
>         return mimeType;
>     }
> ```